# log4j / slf4j package-based logging, how to handle frameworks, e.g. spring?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, slf4j

Let's say my application consists of several components which are logged separately:

```
myapp.log
myapp-foo.log
myapp-bar.log
```

My classes all define a "standard" java logger:

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ThisClass.class);
```

Logging for components "foo" and "bar" is set up via package-based configuration (each of which logs to it's own logfile) :

```
<Logger name="com.mycompany.myapp.foo" level="info">
    <AppenderRef ref="foo"/>
</Logger>

<Logger name="com.mycompany.myapp.bar" level="info">
    <AppenderRef ref="bar"/>
</Logger>
```

This works fine, up to the point where we want to see log messages from a framework we use, such as spring, since spring log statements end up in `myapp.log` - not `myapp-foo.log` or `myapp-bar.log`.

It's convenient to have one `log4j.xml` or `log4j2.xml` file, but can we use package-based log configuration in this way -  *and still have spring log statements logged to the "correct" log file, `myapp-foo.log` of `myapp-bar.log`*?

Or is there a different solution?

Edit: we are using spring 4.0.3.RELEASE and log4j2

Comment: Do you need your spring logs also in myapp-foo.log and myapp-bar.log ? Is it the question ? If yes than create one more aopender for spring and provide same log file in appender.

Comment: Yes, that's the plan. We have ended up actually having a separate `log4j2-modulename.xml` which specifies one logfile.